# How can I convert date format from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, function, datetime

I have a specific date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD but want to convert it to YYYY-MM format in a table. I want this change to apply to the full table. can anyone help me out, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your field stored as DATE format in your table or as a STRING ?

Comment: Dates *should* be in a `date` datatype, which doesn't have a format.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: *want to convert it to YYYY-MM format **in a table.*** Forget about it. Forever. There exists STORING and there exists DISPLAYING. Do nothing with storing - i.e. do nothing with your data. Change the displaying - i.e. retrieve the data not as-is but formatting it into the format which you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `date` datatype or the-like (`datetime`, `timestamp`), you can use `date_format()` to represent your date in the target format:

```
date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m')
```

This returns a *string* in the target format. It does not make sense to *convert* your `date` column to a string though. Keep that column as it is, and maybe use a computed column to automatically derived the string representation you want:

```
create table mytable (
    ...
    mydate date,
    mynewcol varchar(7) as (date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m'))
)
```

Comment: Yes, I got the solution from this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE_FORMAT function of MySQL, for more information please [visit](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%Y-%m");
```